# Stop rxJava observable chain execution on disposing

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

While debugging rxJava network call in an app i came across to a situation, that if we `dispose` or `clear` disposal object returned by subscription of a chain of `observables` then only first `observable` gets disposed not other chained `observables` by `flatMap`.

Have a look at following demo code snippet:

```
CompositeDisposable testCompositeDisposal = new CompositeDisposable();

private void testLoadData() {
    Disposable disposable = Observable.create(sbr -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Log.w("Debug: ", "First: " + i);
            sbr.onNext(true);
        }
        sbr.onComplete();
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).flatMap(value -> Observable.create(sbr -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Log.w("Debug: ", "Second: " + i);
            sbr.onNext(true);
        }
        sbr.onComplete();
    })).doOnNext(value -> {
        Log.w("Debug: ", "doONNext");
    }).doOnDispose(()-> {
        Log.w("Debug: ", "doOnDispose: observable has been disposed");
    }).subscribe();

    testCompositeDisposal.add(disposable);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    testCompositeDisposal.clear();
}
```

**output:**

```
 W/Debug:: First: 0
 W/Debug:: doOnDispose: observable has been disposed // I dispose Observable chain here.
 W/Debug:: First: 1
 W/Debug:: First: 2
 W/Debug:: First: 3
 W/Debug:: First: 4
```

As you can just see in above log output that when i dispose given rxJava observable chain only first observable stops emitting items.

I want to stop all observable those are chained.

What is the idiomatic way to solve this issue?

Comment: all those Observable.create stuff looks very evilish :-). First: you need to add flatmapped observables to your composite disposable aswell. Second: Dont you create() everywhere. This is not how rxjava is designed. Observable.just( ...) or Observable.range() with .timeout/.timer/.delay works well.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold this is just a demo of my implementation. I used timer here to simulate a network call. I have used doOnSubscribe to get disposable for flatmapped observable. It is throwing weird exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things:

- `flatMap` may pre-consume items from upstream (up to 16 on android);
- Second and more applicable to your use-case, before you call `onNext` you should check whether the observer is disposed (via `.isDisposed()`) and abort when that happens.

Also, the *second* `flatMap` gets terminated (actually it never gets called).  The *first* one continues.

**EDIT**

```
private void testLoadData() { 
    Disposable disposable = Observable.create(sbr -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if(sbr.isDisposed()) return;  // this will cause subscription to terminate.
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Log.w("Debug: ", "First: " + i);
            sbr.onNext(true); 
        } 
        sbr.onComplete(); 
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).flatMap(value -> Observable.create(sbr -> { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
            Log.w("Debug: ", "Second: " + i); 
            sbr.onNext(true); 
        } 
        sbr.onComplete(); 
    })).doOnNext(value -> { 
        Log.w("Debug: ", "doONNext"); 
    }).doOnDispose(()-> { 
        Log.w("Debug: ", "doOnDispose: observable has been disposed"); 
    }).subscribe(); 

    testCompositeDisposal.add(disposable); 
}
```

Comment: I can cope up with second point, but is it the only way to do this? I mean is it idiomatic way?

Comment: one more thing, how do i abort? by throwing error observable?

Comment: Yes, that's the proper way to terminate the iteration. And when the subscriber is disposed, you just return from the lambda, no need for anything else. Note that you didn't explain what your use case is, as everything you've shown so far can be done with existing operators.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks. My use case is that i need to call a webservice and when response comes store that. In between when user leave the application database object is closed and exception "database not open" is thrown. Hence app crashes.

Comment: And what if we do not work with create, but use retrofit2 +RxJava?

Comment: @DuosDuo My opinion has changed after working with RxJava2 and retrofit for 3 years; I believe that one should actively try to avoid explicit creation, and instead rely on the built-in operators. In our projects it's ~1 explicit `subscribe` and 1 explicit `generate` per 30K SLOC, and these are for really funky flows that weren't decomposable.